# Configuring provider after OndeviceReady

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Hi I am trying to create a log service in angularjs and phonegap to write some logs in my mobile.

So far I have tried to implement a provider so I can configure easily what is the File to write ( `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);`) and also if I want to write logs in an external file.

The problem is if I wrap the config lines in OnDeviceReady event the configuration of the provider is not working properly,

So my question is, since I want to have a global variable to write everything on the same file How can I configure a provider that needs to be executed after OnDeviceReady?

Implementation of the app.js

```
MyApp.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider','logItProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, logIt) {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

        alert("deviceReady!");
        var file = "myFile";
        logIt.setFile(file);
        logIt.setLogEnable(true);

    }
```

This is the implementation of my provider:

```
angular.module('logger', [])
    .provider('logIt', function(){
        // internal configuration data; configured through setter function
        this.file = 'Default';
        this.callsParseCounter = 0;
        this.isLogEnable = false;

        this.$get = function() {
            var file = this.file;
            var numberOfCalls = this.callsParseCounter;
            var isLogEnable = this.isLogEnable;
            return {
                getFile: function() {
                    return "Hello, " + file + "!"
                },

                writeLog: function(message){
                    if(this.isLogEnable)
                    {

                    }

                },
                incrementParseCounter: function()
                {
                    if(isLogEnable)
                    {
                        numberOfCalls++;
                        this.callsParseCounter = numberOfCalls;
                    }
                },

                getNumberOfCalls: function(){

                    return numberOfCalls;

                }


            }
        };
        this.setFile = function(file) {
            this.file = file;
        };
        this.setCallParseCounter = function(callsParseCounter)
        {
            this.callsParseCounter = callsParseCounter;
        };
        this.setLogEnable = function(isLogEnable)
        {
            this.isLogEnable = isLogEnable;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Maybe you can bootstrap angular manually after the device is ready?  Here is the doc: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap